# Custom Control that exposes Button Control's OnClick event

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I need to design a custom control that is basically going to be a fancy button, let's call it `CtrlButton`.

I want to drop these on my blank form, then go to the Events for my control and specify what to do for the **Click** event.

If my custom control `CtrlButton` contained 1 Windows Form Button named `button1`, could I simply expose the underlying Click event handler for the `button1`?

```
public EventHandler Click {
  get { return button1.Click; }
  set { button1.Click = value; }
}
```

This code doesn't work! But, that's essentially what I'm trying to do.

**EDIT:** I see I was awarded Popular Question for this post, yet it still sits there at -1. If this question helps you find your answer, please vote it up.

Comment: Derive from Button, not UserControl.  A user control is not meant to be a clickable item, it is meant to be a bag for other controls.  Much like Form.  When you derive from Button, you don't have to do anything with Click, you just inherit the regular and sane behavior.

Comment: Quote from the FAQ: *If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button.Click is an event, not a property. You can't get and set its value, because it's not a property; you can only add and remove handlers, because it's an event and that's how events work.

But you can write your own event with custom `add` and `remove` handlers that wrap the Button:

```
public event EventHandler Click {
    add { button1.Click += value; }
    remove { button1.Click -= value; }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what my original question asked, and this is how I am solving the problem at the moment. Eventually, I may take  Gregory A Beamer's approach and inherit the `Button`, but not today.

Answer (score 3):

If this is derived from a standard Button control, as this is:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsControlLibrary1
{
   public class RedButton : Button
   {
       public RedButton()
       {
           base.BackColor = Color.Red;
       }
   }
}
```

the events are available. If you have completely customized to make your own button, you will have to wire up all of the events, ala [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36axhcy.aspx).

Comment: OK, that works - but how would I create a button that has a border around it that turns `Yellow` when selected and `Red` when that selection is not valid? (that's a requirement of my spec sheet here) Currently, I've got a `Button` centered inside a `Panel` control that I can change the `BackColor` on.

Comment: You still can override the native events and do something like what you wish. Or, if you feel really randy, you can write new ones. :-). Now, if you need the entire panel, then a standard "custom control" template is the way, as you are merging a lot of controls. When doing that, you will have to create events to map to the control events. But, if this is just a button you need, try inheriting from button and then coding to the events exposed to do what you desire.